# How to Read&Write preserving the class

Tags: r, file, csv, optimization, save

Is there a way to save a *data frame* data and keep attributes classes? I find it very annoying to read the file, and convert *e.g*: from *character* to *fastposix*, from *numeric* to *factor*. Specially knowing this was all set before.

Comment: As what do you want to save it?

Comment: I don't even have int mind the options. I only know .csv files or other common character separating files. I will be pleased with something is functional

Comment: Just use `save` or `saveRDS`. These functions can save any R object. You then use `load` or `readRDS` to restore them back.

Comment: *save/read* **RDS** works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nicola pointted out. The function saveRDS and loadRDS does the work